# Metadata and Mithril

Tags: metadata, node

From my understanding you need to run a full node to add metadata to a txn.

Will it be possible to do this without a full node using Mithril?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a full node to add metadata to a transaction. Most wallets have this function, for example the wallet Eternl has it.

Comment: ok great thanks for clearing up.